# Change text color of search bar ios

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

Is it possible to change the text color of the search bar? I don't seem to have access to the UISearchBarTextField class...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

firstly,  you find the subview in `UISearchBar`, then  find the `UITextField` in sub View then change color

Try this code:-

```
 for(UIView *subView in searchBar.subviews){
            if([subView isKindOfClass:UITextField.class]){
                [(UITextField*)subView setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
            }
        }
```

for Ios 5 +

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Comment: Doing it this way will probably work but is breakable in case apple decides to play with the view hierarchy, please see my solution below using appearance protocol.

Answer (score 11):

As of iOS 5, the right way to do this is using the appearance protocol.

For example:

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTextColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the attributes like so, call this in your controller.

```
[[UITextField appearanceWhenContainedIn:[self class], nil] setDefaultTextAttributes:@{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:[UIColor whiteColor], NSFontAttributeName:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14]}];
```

*note that this will change all UITextFields in your controller

Answer (score 2):

The original `UISearchBar` hierarchy has changed since the original post and the `UITextField` is no longer a direct subview.  The below code makes no assumptions about the `UISearchBar` hierarchy.

This is also useful when you don't want to change the search bar's text color throughout the entire application (i.e. using [appearanceWhenContainedIn](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAppearance_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfcm/UIAppearance/appearanceWhenContainedIn:)).

```
/**
 * A recursive method which sets all UITextField text color within a view.
 * Makes no assumptions about the original view's hierarchy.
 */
+(void) setAllTextFieldsWithin:(UIView*)view toColor:(UIColor*)color
{
    for(UIView *subView in view.subviews)
    {
        if([subView isKindOfClass:UITextField.class])
        {
            [(UITextField*)subView setTextColor:color];
        }
        else
        {
            [self setAllTextFieldsWithin:subView toColor:color];
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[MyClass setAllTextFieldsWithin:self.mySearchBar toColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
```